# How to know which FormField is invalid in Flutter on the press of the Submit button?

Tags: flutter, dart

From: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      ...
    }
  },
  child: Text('Submit'),
),
```

Here `_formKey` is the `GlobalKey`.

`_formKey.currentState!.validate()` This line will raise an error if any of the FormFields is invalid, but we won't know which one is it talking about.

Ofcourse we can write validation code inside each FormField but when we press the submit button, at that time how do we know which FormField is invalid?